# Complex String Conversion To JSON Format

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a complex string conversion to `JSON` and bit unaware how to do it. Basically, the requirement is a function to take a string parameter and return expected data in specific `JSON` format. So for the function, I can do the following:

```
function myfunction(value)
{
  console.log(value);
}
```

As I am a newbie in `JSON` format and was seeing some of the tutorials to convert a string into `JSON` format, finally found this for the conversion:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify({ a: 10, b: 20 }));
```

So for my case, I can do the below, I guess:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(value));
```

Now the string format I've, is bit complex and not sure, how could I do the conversion as the following as it implies some logic?

**The input**:

```
if($A == $B) {
    if($C == $D) {
        if($E == $F) {

        } else if($G == $H) {

        } else if($I == $J) {

        }
        else if($K == $L) {

        } else if($M == $N) {
          if($AAA == $BBB) {

          }
          else if($CCC == $DDD) {
          }
        }

    } else if($O == $P) {
        if($Q == $R) {
            if($S == $T) {
                if($U == $V) {

                }
            }
        }
    }
} else if($W == $X) {
     if($C == $D) {
        if($E == $F) {

        } else if($G == $H) {

        } else if($I == $J) {

        }
        if($K == $L) {

        } else if($M == $N) {
          if($AAA == $BBB) {

          }
          else if($CCC == $DDD) {

          }
        }

    } else if($O == $P) {
        if($Q == $R) {
            if($S == $T) {
                if($U == $V) {

                }
            }
        }
    }

} else if($Y == $Z) {

}
```

**The output**:

```
{
"or":[
  {
    "and":[
      {
        "field": "A",
        "operator": "==",
        "value": "B"
      },
      {
        "or":[
          {
            "and":[
              {
                "field": "C",
                "operator": "==",
                "value": "D"
              },
              {
                "and":[
                  {
                    "or":[
                      {
                        "field": "E",
                        "operator": "==",
                        "value": "F"
                      },
                      {
                        "field": "G",
                        "operator": "==",
                        "value": "H"
                      },
                      {
                        "field": "I",
                        "operator": "==",
                        "value": "J"
                      },
                      {
                        "field": "K",
                        "operator": "==",
                        "value": "L"
                      },
                      {
                        "and":[{
                            "field": "M",
                            "operator": "==",
                            "value": "N"
                          },
                          {
                            "and":[
                              {
                                "or":[
                                  {
                                    "field": "AAA",
                                    "operator": "==",
                                    "value": "BBB"
                                  },
                                  {
                                    "field": "CCC",
                                    "operator": "==",
                                    "value": "DDD"
                                  }
                                ]
                              }
                            ]
                          }
                        ]
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                ] 
              }
            ]
          },
          {
        "or":[
          {
            "and":[
              {
                "field": "O",
                "operator": "==",
                "value": "P"
              },
              {
                "and":[
                  {
                    "and":[
                      {
                        "and":[
                          {
                            "field": "U",
                            "operator": "==",
                            "value": "V"
                          }
                        ]
                      },
                      {
                        "field": "S",
                        "operator": "==",
                        "value": "T"
                      }
                    ]
                  },
                  {
                    "field": "Q",
                    "operator": "==",
                    "value": "R"
                  }
                ] 
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "and":[
      {
        "field": "W",
        "operator": "==",
        "value": "X"
      },
      {
        "or":[
          {
            "and":[
              {
                "field": "C",
                "operator": "==",
                "value": "D"
              },
              {
                "and":[
                  {
                    "or":[
                      {
                        "field": "E",
                        "operator": "==",
                        "value": "F"
                      },
                      {
                        "field": "G",
                        "operator": "==",
                        "value": "H"
                      },
                      {
                        "field": "I",
                        "operator": "==",
                        "value": "J"
                      },
                      {
                        "field": "K",
                        "operator": "==",
                        "value": "L"
                      },
                      {
                        "and":[{
                            "field": "M",
                            "operator": "==",
                            "value": "N"
                          },
                          {
                            "and":[
                              {
                                "or":[
                                  {
                                    "field": "AAA",
                                    "operator": "==",
                                    "value": "BBB"
                                  },
                                  {
                                    "field": "CCC",
                                    "operator": "==",
                                    "value": "DDD"
                                  }
                                ]
                              }
                            ]
                          }
                        ]
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                ] 
              }
            ]
          },
          {
        "or":[
          {
            "and":[
              {
                "field": "O",
                "operator": "==",
                "value": "P"
              },
              {
                "and":[
                  {
                    "and":[
                      {
                        "and":[
                          {
                            "field": "U",
                            "operator": "==",
                            "value": "V"
                          }
                        ]
                      },
                      {
                        "field": "S",
                        "operator": "==",
                        "value": "T"
                      }
                    ]
                  },
                  {
                    "field": "Q",
                    "operator": "==",
                    "value": "R"
                  }
                ] 
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "field": "O",
    "operator": "==",
    "value": "P"
  }]
}
```

**N.B**: This is a test case and struggling to make it work. Any ideas would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Rule of thumb: You never mess around manually with JSON in string form, you always decode it first, and then work with the resulting data structure. But what your actual question is here, is rather unclear to me.

Comment: It's more about an algorythm problem than a programation problem.